# UTF-8 Font Embed in Mobile

Tags: cordova, embed, font-face

I am developing a application with PhoneGap and embedding Persian fonts in CSS.

When an HTML file is open with the desktop browser, everything is correct, but in the mobile-installed app, some embedded numbers and other characters use the originally-defined fonts.

**How can I solve this problem?**